# Need Jackson serializer for Double and need to specify precision at runtime

Tags: java, json, jackson, serialization

There are many posts about creating Jackson serializers for numbers, currency, etc. For engineering applications, there is often a need to set the precision on numbers based on the units or other criteria.

For example, spatial coordinates might be constrained to 5 or 6 digits after the decimal point, and temperature might be constrained to 2 digits after the decimal point. Default serializer behavior that has too many digits or truncated exponential notation is not good.  What I need is something like:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=MyDoubleSerializer.class, precision=6) double myValue;
```

and better yet be able to specify the precision at run-time.  I am also using a MixIn.  I could write a serializer for each class but hoped to specify on specific values.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

You may use Jackson's `ContextualSerializer` to achieve desired serialization as shown below.

Firstly, create an annotation to capture precision

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Precision {
    int precision();
}
```

Next, create a contextual serializer for `Double` type which looks for `Precision` annotation on the field to be serialized and then create a new serializer for the specified precision.

```
public class DoubleContextualSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private int precision = 0;

    public DoubleContextualSerializer (int precision) {
        this.precision = precision;
    }

    public DoubleContextualSerializer () {

    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if (precision == 0) {
            gen.writeNumber(value.doubleValue());
        } else {
            BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
            bd = bd.setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            gen.writeNumber(bd.doubleValue());
        }

    }
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException {
        Precision precision = property.getAnnotation(Precision.class);
        if (precision != null) {
            return new DoubleContextualSerializer (precision.precision());
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Finally, annotate your field to use custom serializer and set precision

```
public class Bean{

   @JsonSerialize(using = DoubleContextualSerializer .class)
   @Precision(precision = 2)
   private double doubleNumber;

}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This almost works.  BTW you have a typo "Serilaizer".  The problem I have now is I am using a MixIn so that I don't pollute POJOs with Jackson annotations.  The MixIn looks like: `@JsonSerialize(using=JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer.class) @FormatterPrecision(precision=2) abstract Double getValue();`  The `@FormatterPrecision` is disallowed at the location.

Comment: It is because I had configured annotation to be used only at field level via `@Target({ElementType.FIELD)})`. You can configure for methods, constructors etc. I have edited the answer to allow methods too by adding `ElementType.METHOD`

Comment: The `ElementType.METHOD` suggestion worked.  Below is my solution using DecimalFormat rather than BigDecimal, with hopefully good performance.

Comment: Using this code as is with the following annotations `@JsonSerialize(using = DoubleContextualSerializer.class)
  @Precision(precision = 8)
  private Double value;` it is not preventing this value `1e-8` from remaining in scientific notation.  Will post a solution as soon as I find it.

Answer (score 1):

I used most of the suggested code but did the following, which uses DecimalFormat to do the formatting, which required outputting the raw text:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.ContextualSerializer;

/**
 * Custom serializer to serialize Double to a specified precision in output string.
 * The @FormatterPrecision(precision=2) annotation needs to have been specified, for example:
 * <pre>
 * @JsonSerialize(using=JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer.class) @FormatterPrecision(precision=6) abstract Double getLatitude();
 * </pre>
 * @author sam
 *
 */
public class JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Double> implements ContextualSerializer {

    /**
     * Precision = number of digits after the decimal point to display.
     * Last digit will be rounded depending on the value of the next digit.
     */
    private int precision = 4;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer ( ) {

    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param precision number of digits after the decimal to format numbers.
     */
    public JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer ( int precision ) {
            this.precision = precision;
    }

    /**
     * Format to use.  Create an instance so it is shared between serialize calls.
     */
    private DecimalFormat format = null;

    /**
     *
     */
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider provider, BeanProperty property ) throws JsonMappingException {
            FormatterPrecision precision = property.getAnnotation(FormatterPrecision.class);
            if ( precision != null ) {
                    return new JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer(precision.precision());
            }
            return this;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the format has been created.
     */
    private DecimalFormat getFormat () {
            if ( this.format == null ) {
                    // No format so create it
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder("0.");
                    for ( int i = 0; i < this.precision; i++ ) {
                            b.append("0");
                    }
                    this.format = new DecimalFormat(b.toString());
            }
            return this.format;
    }

    /**
     * Serialize a double
     */
    @Override
    public void serialize(Double value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider ) throws IOException {
            if ( (value == null) || value.isNaN() ) {
                    jgen.writeNull();
            }
            else {
                    DecimalFormat format = getFormat();
                    jgen.writeRawValue(format.format(value));
            }
    }
}
```

I am using a MixIn, so that class has:

```
public abstract class StationJacksonMixIn {

    @JsonCreator
    public StationJacksonMixIn () {

    }

    // Serializers to control formatting
    @JsonSerialize(using=JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer.class) 
    @FormatterPrecision(precision=6) abstract Double getLatitude();
    @JsonSerialize(using=JacksonJsonDoubleSerializer.class) 
    @FormatterPrecision(precision=6) abstract Double getLongitude();
}
```

And, finally, enable the MixIn in the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().
                addMixIn(Station.class,StationJacksonMixIn.class);
```

It works well to provide a precision where it applies globally on the data field.

Comment: Although the mixin option is nice, the `new DecimalFormat(pattern)` creates a format using default locale, which for some regions (e.g. some european countries) means decimal and thousands separators different from those used by default when printing a double in java. As a result this may create a json-incompabitle number format. Rounding using BigDecimal seems more portable option to me.

Comment: It's easy to get a DecimalFormat (NumberFormat in fact) for a desired Locale to adhere to a specific decimal separator formatting, e.g.: 
`NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(5);
System.out.println("1/3 = " + formatter.format(1d/3);`

Answer (score 1):

I tried many methods when serializing floats. But I couldn't succeed. Finally, I found the solution by writing custom serializer.

According to this solution, all float type classes should be serialized with Jackson so that the decimal number (precision) is 4, as follows.

**Custom Serializer** :

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

public class CustomFloatSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Float> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Float value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(String.format("%.4f", value));
    }
}
```

**Spring Boot Object Mapper Configuration** :

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

@Configuration
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public void customize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Float.class, new CustomFloatSerializer());
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After my initial more complex attempt, I found a simpler solution that works well.  This involves using `BigDecimal` where appropriate only for output formatting.  For example, the following code has `getValueFormatted` method that formats the value to the correct number of digits.  In this case, the output JSON uses a short element name `v` rather than `value` and `@JsonProperty("v")` is used to indicate that the `getValueFormatted` method should be used to return the value for output. I did not put in a MixIn but could do that.  This adds a method to the normal object but that is OK for REST service code.

```
  /**
   * Return the data value.
   * Ignored for JSON output because use getValueFormatted instead.
   */
  @JsonIgnore
  public Double getValue () {
    return this.value;
  }

  /**
   * Return the value formatted to appropriate number of digits.
   * This is used with serialization to output.
   * Use for JSON output because it is formatted to the correct number of digits.
   * @return the data value formatted to the appropriate number of digits.
   */
  @JsonProperty("v")
  public BigDecimal getValueFormatted () {
    // BigDecimal does not handle the concept of NaN and therefore can't serialize those values as Double does.
    if ( (this.value == null) || this.value.isNaN() || this.value.isInfinite() ) {
      return null;
    }
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(this.value).setScale(this.valueDigits,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd;
  }
```