# Double in 2 decimal format

Tags: java, decimalformat

I want to send my `Double` value in json with 2 decimal points. I am using `DecimalFormat` class like `DecimalFormt.format(value)`, but it gives value in `String`. I want the same in `Double` type. Is there any way for it as value in `json` should be in `Double` only not as `String`?

Comment: Have you tried @Precision(precision = 2)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110624/need-jackson-serializer-for-double-and-need-to-specify-precision-at-runtime

Comment: If you are not using jackson, try using BigDecimal, set the rounding mode, and then either send the BigDecimal back out through the json and let it convert, or get the double out of the big decimal.

Comment: How are you converting the Java value to JSON? Are you using Jackson or Gson?

Comment: @Ashu yes, it worked. Thanks.