# Jackson Custom Serializer shows the same context for 2 different field during the Json Serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am trying to create a JSON based on my Object class POJO. For some fields, I would like to use the CustomSerializer as I would like to create the fields according to my requirement. Hence, I have created the `CustomSerializer.class`.

The `CustomSerializer` will be called by 2 different fields in my `POJO` and I would like to handle the things differently based on which field is making the call. For one of the fields (`extensions`) I would like to have the `fieldName` and for other field (`withoutExtensions`) I do not wish to have the `fieldname` in my JSON.

The problem I am facing is that when `CustomSerializer` is called then I am getting the same `fieldname` for both the calls due to which I am unable to make a differentiation which field is currently calling the `CustomSerializer`.

Following code samples will provide more clarity on the issue I am facing:

`Customer` POJO class used for serializing the JSON:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    private String isA;
    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    private Map<String, Object> extensions = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, Object> withoutExtensions = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    public Map<String, Object> getWithoutExtensions() {
        return withoutExtensions;
    }

}
```

Following is my `CustomSerializer` which will be called by 2 fields (extensions and withoutExtensions) during the creation of JSON:

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) {
        //I would like to create the outer object for "Extensions" but do not want to create outer object for "WithoutExtensions"
        
         System.out.println(gen.getOutputContext().getCurrentName());

        //In my case for both "Extensions" and "WithoutExtensions" i get the "currentName" as "Extensions" how can I ensure which field is calling this sealizer at
        // present
    }
}
```

Following is my `Main` class which will create a JSON:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        final Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.setName("Jackson");

        Map<String, Object> extensions = new HashMap<>();
        extensions.put("WithObject", "With");
        customer.setExtensions(extensions);

        Map<String, Object> withoutExtensions = new HashMap<>();
        extensions.put("WithoutObject", "Without");
        customer.setWithoutExtensions(withoutExtensions);

        final String eventAsJson = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(customer);
        System.out.println(eventAsJson);
    }
}
```

As we can see when I run the application the `CustomSerializer` would print `extensions` in both cases. I believe it should print `extensions` only once and in the next case either it should provide `withoutExtensions` or empty string.

I just wanted to know if this an bug on the Jackson part or is there any work-around that I can try to differentiate which field is making a call to my `CustomSerializer`.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A. Create two `Map` serialisers where one creates outer object and another not

Pros:

- Easy to implement
- Easy to test
- One class does exactly one thing
- `Map` serialiser which does not create outer object could be replaced by custom `Map` serialiser (if possible)

Cons:

- Could be problematic if they need to share state.
- Possibly duplicated code

### B. Implement [ContextualSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/ContextualSerializer.html) interface

Pros:

- Can be configured for every field separately
- Can share state if needed. User control how many instances are created.

Cons:

- Does more than 1 thing
- Can be easily over complicated

Examples:

- [Need Jackson serializer for Double and need to specify precision at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110624/need-jackson-serializer-for-double-and-need-to-specify-precision-at-runtime)
- [Jackson custom annotation for custom value serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342097/jackson-custom-annotation-for-custom-value-serialization)
- [Deserialize to String or Object using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55433367/deserialize-to-string-or-object-using-jackson)
- [Jackson - deserialize inner list of objects to list of one higher level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424576/jackson-deserialize-inner-list-of-objects-to-list-of-one-higher-level)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. This really helped me and I choose option `B` as I felt that would be easiest to reduce the redundant code. I accept this answer and thanks again. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response from @Michal I modified the code and it worked for both the scenario. Posting the complete code sample as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

`Customer.class` added the `@Extensions` on required fields:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    private String isA;
    private String name;

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    @Extensions(extension = "extensions")
    private Map<String, Object> extensions = new HashMap<>();

    private Map<String, Object> withoutExtensions = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    @Extensions(extension = "withoutExtensions")
    public Map<String, Object> getWithoutExtensions() {
        return withoutExtensions;
    }

}
```

`CustomSerializer`:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> implements ContextualSerializer {

    private String context = "";

    public CustomSerializer(String context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) {
        if (this.context.equals("extensions")) {
            System.out.println("Extensions : " + this.context);
        } else if (this.context.equals("withoutExtensions")) {
            System.out.println("Without Extensions : " + this.context);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider serializerProvider, BeanProperty beanProperty) throws JsonMappingException {
        Extensions extensions = beanProperty.getAnnotation(Extensions.class);
        if (extensions != null) {
            return new CustomSerializer(extensions.extension());
        }
        return this;
    }
}


@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Extensions {
    String extension();
}
```