# Jackson ignore subclass field after create custom serializer for superclass

Tags: java, json, jackson

I create a cuztom serializer for superclass, then all subclass serialized without it's own fields.

```java
class Super{
   double f1;
}

class Sub extends Super{
   double f2;
}

class CuztomSerializer extends StdSerializer<Super>{
   @Override
    public void serialize(Super s, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeNumberField("f1", BigDecimal.valueOf(s.getF1()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

As the codes above, `Sub` instance serialized only has `f1` field. How to reserve `f2` field?

Comment: hi perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44110624/need-jackson-serializer-for-double-and-need-to-specify-precision-at-runtime

Comment: @jspcal thx. it helps in this demo, but in my real business, the CustomSerializer do more work actually, setting serialization precision maybe not enough.

Comment: Why don't you custom serialize `f1` instead of the entire object?

Comment: @shmosel that's only a simple demo to show my problem. In real business the custom serializer is more complex.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to say, but if the problem is more complex than you're describing, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: @shmosel I just want to know if it is possible to make subclass fields serialized in this situation by some settings? If not, I would consider other way instead of serializer for entire superclass. Sorry for my poor english,  hope I have expressed my intent clearly.